# Same gMaps query on different machines returns different zoom levels. Why?

Tags: google-maps

For a strange reason the same query (Moscow, Russia) via G-Maps API (geocode method on google.maps.Geocoder object) is returning two different zoom levels on two different machines (level 10 and level 9).
We're just trying to understand how that could be possible.
Can the query result be influenced by some local settings?
Any suggestion is REALLY appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
Teo

Comment: Not sure, but it seems to me that the zoom level depends on the size of the <div> : is it fixed or a % of the screen size ?

Comment: Actually the container div is in %.

Comment: The main difference between the two machines (two MacBooks Pro) is that one of them is Retina. 
However we tried to make the query with a reduced viewport but nothing changed...

Comment: Can you provide an example page where this happens?

Answer (score 0):

If the size of the div in absolute pixels is different, Google Maps (or the Google Maps API) will fit the div as sized on your monitor.  If the div has a fixed pixel size the same map should result in the same zoom level.